# Meraki blocking js and css from good sites that use Cloudfront.net

Tags: firewall, blocking, meraki

We have a Meraki device in place that is blocking static resources (i.e. js and css files) from Cloudfront.net and causing problems with valid sites loading. One specific error (below) indicated it was due to a mismatched MIME type.

The stylesheet http://wired.meraki.com:8090/blocked.cgi?blocked_server=XX.XX.X.XXX:80&blocked_url=http%3A%2F%2Fdtzbdy9anri2p.cloudfront.net%2Fcache%2Fb7e5c1a7c835e5875ce8e562f824a3d47915f6e4%2Ftelerik%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&blocked_categories=bc_056 was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

A couple sites affected: 
https://www.quartzy.com/
http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-all-min-js-missing-in-the-last-build

Anyone know how to prevent Meraki from blocking these? Or other thoughts on how to handle this? Cloudfront.net is not explicity blocked as far as we could tell.

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same problem. I had to whitelist cloudfront in the Meraki MX console.